# How many forms can "I avoid telling him" be in the passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

I need to find out how many forms the emphasized sentence can be in the passive voice.

> *I avoid telling him*

Is it correct to say, "Telling him is avoided" in terms of signifying the process of (telling) informing him?

Answer (score 3):

There are two actions described by verbs in the sentence, avoiding and telling. So basically there are three options:

Making *avoid* passive:

> Telling him is avoided (by me).

Making *telling* passive:

> I avoid him being told.

Making both passive:

> Him being told is avoided (by me).

Needless to say the last version wouldn't win any prizes for style or readability.

Comment: Such a great answer. My gratitude.